# Денвер не работает кодировка

Tags: кодировка, denwer

С самой кодировкой всё в порядке. Но на сайте мне понадобились цитаты. Их я занёс в файл .txt. Далее создал файл .php где выбирается рандомная строчка. Потом это файл я подключил к главному. А выводится вместо цитаты кракозябра.

Comment: пора уже забыть о денвер, есть его аналог тоже лёгкий [appserver](https://www.appserv.org/en/)

Comment: а вообще htaccess решает эту проблему и если вы пишите код в notepad++ то надо сохранять код именно в utf8 under Boom

Comment: Спасибо помогло